# Setting a static IP upon Qemu VM creation

Tags: networking, qemu

I am starting a VM using Qemu:

```
sudo qemu-system-arm \     
-kernel kernel-qemu-4.14.79-stretch \
-append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
-hda raspbian-stretch-lite_1.qcow \
-cpu arm1176 -m 256 \
-M versatilepb \
-dtb versatile-pb.dtb \
-no-reboot \
-serial stdio \
-display none \
-net nic,addr=10.10.10.11/24, -net bridge,br=br0
```

However, setting the IP of the virtual machine like this doesn't work. Instead, an entirely different IP is set. Is there an easy way to do this?

In case there isn't, is it possible to find out the IP of a started VM? Maybe by using the MAC which is settable on Qemu start?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

More a workaround than a real solution:

Since specifying MAC addresses for NICs is possible, using dnsmasq as a DHCP server on the bridge can reach that goal:

```
sudo dnsmasq --conf-file=dnsmasq.conf
```

The conf file should include following lines:

```
port=0
interface=br0
no-dhcp-interface=eth0
dhcp-range=10.10.1.10,10.10.1.150,12h
dhcp-host=2c:4d:11:12:11:11,10.10.1.25
```

`port=0` disables the DNS server and `no-dhcp-interface=eth0` makes sure that the physical interface is not touched (change if your's is a different one).
Now, `dhcp-host=<MAC>,<IP>` can be used to create manual mappings. And a Qemu VM with the IP 10.10.1.25 can be started with:

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -net nic,macaddr=2c:4d:11:12:11:11 -net bridge,br=br0
```

Assuming a bridge interface has been set up:

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
```